# how to use variable in firestore query

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I use firebase firestore db. This project have two main collection "securecollection" and "publiccollection". The securecollection is where all important data is stored and only accessible to authenticated users. But in order for some information to be visible to guest users, I am copying them into the publiccollection. Then, I want to save the id of this newly created public document in the secure document.

When I write a variable
`db.collection('securecollection').doc(secureDocid).update({` inside the query sentence, I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o.indexOf is not a function

If I write the id as text `db.collection('securecollection').doc('7llDqIWlmE5VM69Zzle2').update({`, the code works.

Here is my code:

```
function toggleOlustur(secureDocid) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection("securecollection").get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.id == secureDocid) {
          db.collection("publiccollection").add({
              oad: doc.data().oad,
              osad: doc.data().osad,
              opuan: doc.data().opuan,
              odtarih: doc.data().odtarih,
              odurum: "1",
            })
            .then((docRef) => {
              db.collection('securecollection').doc(secureDocid).update({
                preference: docRef.id
              })
            });
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: _"I get an error..."_ - And that error is...? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: `secureDocid = secureDocid;` - What is this supposed to do (other than nothing)?

Comment: Hi Andreas,
Thank you for your reply and warnings.

the error message i get

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o.indexOf is not a function

and the other line is a code that I forgot to delete.

Comment: It sounds like your `secureDocid` is not a string value. `console.log(JSON.stringify(secureDocid))` might help to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you very much @frank, 'JSON.stringify()' works perfectly

Comment: Good to hear.  What was the problem?

Comment: `secureDocid` was not the string value as you said. I added this line `secDocid = (JSON.stringify(secureDocid)); `at the beginning of the function. Thank you very much again. @frank

Comment: Check the documentation of `.doc()` (which should have been the first step). If it expects a string (as the error suggests) then convert `secureDocid` into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`doc()` method](https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) expects a string argument, and from the error message it sounds like your `secureDocid` is not a string value. If you `console.log(JSON.stringify(secureDocid))` you can see what it outputs, which might help to figure out the problem.

Comment: As a "Google Cloud Employee" you should be able to link the documentation of `.doc()` and explain why the error happens and how to fix it. And if only there was a type-specific method to convert vales of that type into a string, like for example `.toString()`

Comment: Hi @Andreas. Frank chose to try to help rather than scold.
Thanks to his help, I solved my problem. This is a good thing.